# How to select the latest record in mysql for each separate id

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select the latest value for each form_id from a table such as:
 [image]

Thanks!

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Let us know when you have a question or need help with something.

Comment: `select form,max(date) from yourtable group by form`

Answer (score 1):

Simple. GROUP BY and MAX:

```
select form, max(date)
from your_table
group by form
```

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.